# What Happens If I Delete ".erlang.cookie" File of Rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, openstack

I accidentally deleted the ".erlang.cookie" file in $HOME on one of rabbitmq cluster nodes.
I found that the cluster status is ok and rabbitmqctl cli works well.
It seems that deleting the cookie file is not a problem but I can not be sure that the cluster is really ok.

so I'd like to know whether the deletion I describe above could be no problem. 
please help me, I would take any advice gratefully.

**additional info**

there are 3 nodes for rabbitmq cluster.
all of them have the same ".erlang.cookie" file in /var/lib/rabbitmq/ , but they have different ".erlang.cookie" file in $HOME .
and the file I accidentally deleted was in $HOME on node1

**rabbitmq.conf:**

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {cluster_partition_handling, autoheal},
    {default_permissions, [<<".*">>, <<".*">>, <<".*">>]},
    {default_vhost, <<"/">>},
    {log_levels, [{connection,info}]},
    {mnesia_table_loading_timeout, 10000},
    {tcp_listen_options, [
      binary,
      {packet, raw},
      {reuseaddr, true},
      {backlog, 128},
      {nodelay, true},
      {exit_on_close, false},
      {keepalive, true}
    ]},
    {default_user, <<"nova">>},
    {default_pass, <<"hq33cCIU">>}
  ]},
  {kernel, [
    {inet_default_connect_options, [{nodelay,true}]},
    {inet_dist_listen_max, 41055},
    {inet_dist_listen_min, 41055},
    {net_ticktime, 10}
  ]}
,
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {listener, [
      {port, 15672}
    ]}
  ]}
].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ and its associated commands use the cookie file in `/var/lib/rabbitmq`. Deleting the file in `$HOME` will be fine.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question :D